# What is the interpretation of $\mu(dx)$ in Lebesgue integral?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

For estimating the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ we calculate the area of rectangles of height $f(x)$ and base $dx$ (Riemann sums). Therefore, we go from $a$ to $b$ with steps of $dx$.

what 's the interpretation of $\mu(dx)$ in $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ and how can we relate it to Lebesgue integral interpretation ?

I already Know Lebesgue integral basics.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this usage? To me it just looks like a typo or a strange way of writing $d\mu$.

Comment: For example , I want to know what does $\Lambda(x)$ mean in integral $E(\sum f(x))=\int f(x)\Lambda(dx)$ where $\Lambda(x)$ is the intensity function of $\Phi$. $\Phi$ is a point process with points of $x$.I know what intensity function is but I don't understand its interpretation.

Comment: The reason it's written like that is to emphasize that the integral is being taken with respect to the measure $\mu$. Sometimes you might also sometimes see $\int f d \mu$, which means the same thing. Writing it out $\mu(dx)$ just emphasizes that $\mu$ is a set function, so you're integrating with respect to the measure of an the tiny set $dx$ on the line.

Answer (score 1):

if you see $dx$ in Riemann integration as the base of the rectangle (keep in mind, that it is infinitely small), then you can understand $\mu ( dx)$ as the measure of the base of such a rectangle (also infinitely small).

Comment: So if $\mu$ is a probability measure on $X$ with corresponding p.d.f. $f_X$, can we say $\int g(x)\mu(dx) = \int g(x)f_X(x)dx$?

Comment: @JoshBone yes, this is indeed true